Stream data from Postgres to http request using Django StreamingHttpResponse
I would like to allow my users to download data from a Postgres DB, no matter the size of the requested data. For that reason, I would like to stream the data from the DB to the user.
I have seen that StreamingHttpResponse is useful to stream an HTTP response and there is a snippet in the Django documentation that shows how to stream a large CSV file.
I have also seen that psycopg2 has some streaming capabilities but I cannot find a way to "connect" the 2 streams.
I have tried something along the lines of:
class Echo:
"""An object that implements just the write method of the file-like
interface.
"""

    def write(self, value):
        """Write the value by returning it, instead of storing in a buffer."""
        return value

def stream(request):
    sql_query = sql.SQL(
            """
            COPY (select * from table) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER
            """)
    # create the file like object            
    pseudo_buffer = Echo()

    # I would like data to flow from the DB to HTTP response
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        return StreamingHttpResponse(cursor.copy_expert(sql_query, pseudo_buffer), content_type="text/csv", headers={"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'},)

I could make many small SQL requests and stream the data chunk by chunk using StreamingHttpResponse, but can I stream the data all the way from the DB to the client with only one DB request?

Please don't use the database as a formatter. You can format this in a streaming manner through Python's csv module.

@willeM_VanOnsem Could you explain why?

because databases are not good with formatting, and often also offer a very small amount of features. Typically you use something like django-import-export. This can talk a lot of formats, and can customize it with custom header names for example. Databases should be used to store, replicate, filter, and aggregate data. Not as some sort of swiss knife to generate exports in a specific format.

Created an enhancement proposal at django-import-export: https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1952#issuecomment-2381791728
